# KML Time Stamp With UTC Conversion Not Working

Tags: kml, google-earth, timestamp

So I have a KML Placemark with a `<when>` tag in it that has the dateTime that I want, however when I load it into google earth, the `<when>` tag disappears.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
  <Document>
    <Folder targetId="fld1">
      <Placemark>
        <TimeStamp>
          <when>2014-04-15T01:12:06-5:00</when>
        </TimeStamp>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-82.345144,27.648110,164.787275</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
     </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

As soon as I load it into Google Earth, the placemark appears but the When tag does not. Therefore I dont get the timeSlider.

If I simply use the `Z` notation at the end of the time, then it shows `8:00` rather than `1:00` something...

Any help would be great. I am relatively new to KML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, Ha I just noticed that I left out the leading `0` for the hour in the offset. I will leave this Q & A here in case someone else searches something similar.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer (click the tick) after a couple of days. This will remove it from the unanswered list :)